# Is castle activerecord being actively maintained?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I took a look a few weeks ago at the castle project website, which seems to be "under construction".

If you go to the projects page:
http://www.castleproject.org/projects/

And scroll down, active record is listed as an archived project.

Is it actually no longer being worked on?

Comment: You should ask this directly to them IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ActiveRecord has been recently moved to archived projects. This doesn't mean it's dead.

It means none of the main contributors is **actively** working on it.
Pull requests are still being accepted and if someone steps in with a vision and commitment to develop the project it may be brought back from the archived projects list.

Hope that clears the situation a bit.